# Chaining `NSOperation` : Pass result from an operation to the next one

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I've been looking for a way to pass results for chained `NSOperation`. For example, lets assume we have 3 operations chained:

1. `Operation1` to download `JSON` data from server
2. `Operation2` to parse & model JSON received
3. `Operation3` to download user images

So Op3 would be dependent on Op2, which is dependent on Op1. But I'm looking for way to pass results from Op1 -> Op2, then from Op2 -> Op3 as:

```
[operation1 startWithURL:url];
[operation2 parseJSONfromOp1IntoModel:JSONData];
[operation3 downloadUserImagesForUser: UserModelObject];
```

and nesting blocks doesn't seem to be a clean readable solution, any idea?

Comment: did you try using `completionBlock`?

Comment: have you seen https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-226/

Comment: I found https://github.com/berzniz/Sequencer a useful library for doing this sort of sequencing.

Comment: Sadly, nesting blocks with custom completion handlers is typical `NSOperation` approach. Or look at promises/futures, e.g. [PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit) or [RSPromise](https://github.com/couchdeveloper/RXPromise).

Comment: @Rob , thanks but i have to stick to SDK and not 3rd party libraries for some reasons, otherwise i would have done it in less than 8 ReactiveCocoa lines :)

Comment: @Wain , yes but it's not typically chaining,more of 1 operation at a time then `updateUI` , operations are not dependant on previous results.

Comment: @GrahamPerks thanks for the Tip

Comment: Very well covered by the WWDC 2015 on NSOperation (and the associated sample code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to chain operations, but don't like the nesting, you can use `NSOperation` subclasses, and then define your own completion handlers:

```
DownloadOperation *downloadOperation = [[DownloadOperation alloc] initWithURL:url];
ParseOperation *parseOperation = [[ParseOperation alloc] init];
DownloadImagesOperation *downloadImagesOperation = [[DownloadImagesOperation alloc] init];

downloadOperation.downloadCompletionHandler = ^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
        return;
    }

    parseOperation.data = data;
    [queue addOperation:parseOperation];
};

parseOperation.parseCompletionHandler = ^(NSDictionary *dictionary, NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
        return;
    }

    NSArray *images = ...;

    downloadImagesOperation.images = images;
    [queue addOperation:downloadImagesOperation];
};

[queue addOperation:downloadOperation];
```

Frankly, though, I'm not sure that's any more intuitive than the nested approach:

```
DownloadOperation *downloadOperation = [[DownloadOperation alloc] initWithURL:url downloadCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
        return;
    }

    ParseOperation *parseOperation = [[ParseOperation alloc] initWithURL:data parseCompletionHandler:^(NSDictionary *dictionary, NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
            return;
        }

        NSArray *images = ...

        DownloadImagesOperation *downloadImagesOperation = [[DownloadImagesOperation alloc] initWithImages:images imageDownloadCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"%@", error);
                return;
            }

            // everything OK
        }];
        [queue addOperation:downloadImagesOperation];
    }];
    [queue addOperation:parseOperation];
}];
[queue addOperation:downloadOperation];
```

By the way, the above assumes that you're familiar with subclassing `NSOperation`, especially the subtleties of creating an asynchronous `NSOperation` subclass (and doing all of the necessary KVO). If you need examples of how that's done, let me know.

Comment: I was going to say the first way looks correct but it has a small mistake. After each operation is configured, dependencies should be set up, and then all 3 operations should be added to the queue, not after each ends. If any errors are returned then cancel the queue.

Comment: Yep, that's another pattern. I deliberately omitted it because it's a bit fragile. When you have operation dependencies, that doesn't necessarily apply their completion handlers, which could run asynchronously on different thread. So, if you're passing data in completion handlers, your `NSOperation` subclasses must call their completion handlers _synchronously_ before the operation finishes. But, it's questionable design to have code integrity contingent upon implementation details of another class. The above options are solely reliant upon public interfaces which is more robust.

Answer (score 2):

**Creating chained operations:**

Create the Op2 from within the completion block of Op1, then use delegation or something similar to set the dependency on the newly created operation. You can use this pattern to chain as many as you want. To pass the result in the completion block, you cannot use `completionBlock` that is on `NSOperation`. You will need to define your own (like I did with `almostFinished`) in order to pass the result through.

```
- (void)someMethod {
    Operation1 *operation1 = [[Operation1 alloc] init];
    operation1.almostFinished = ^(id op1Result) {

        Operation2 *operation2 = [[Operation2 alloc] initWithResultFromOp1: op1Result];
        operation2.almostFinished = ^(id op2Result) {

            Operation3 *operation3 = [[Operation3 alloc] initWithResultFromOp2:op2Result];
            operation3.completionBlock = ^{
                NSLog(@"Operations 1 and 2 waited on me, but now we're all finished!!!);
            };

            [operation2 addDependency:operation3];
            [queue addOperation:operation3];
        };

        [operation1 addDependency:operation2];
        [queue addOperation:operation2];
    };

    [queue addOperation:operation1];
}
```

**Custom Subclass**

You will need to subclass `NSOperation` for this to work. As I mentioned, you need to define your own completion block AND make sure that completion block is called before the operation is truly finished so that you can add the dependency. Instead of adding the dependency in the new completion block, you could add it in a different block or delegate method. This way kept my example concise.

```
@interface Operation: NSOperation {
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^almostFinished)(id result);
@end

@implementation Operation {
    //...

- (void)main {
    //...
    // Call here to allow to add dependencies and new ops
    self.almostFinished(result);  

    // Finish the op
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    // repeat for isExecuting and do whatever else
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
}
@end
```

EDIT: This isn't the most readable thing, but it contains all the code in one method. If you want to get fancy, then place things out in delegate methods or get creative with how you define these things.

Comment: thanks @keithbhunter , i'm giving a shot to subclassing now.